# PyInstaller with NumPy under Linux

Tags: python, linux, numpy, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert my Python program into a stand-alone executable for Windows and Linux. It seemed that PyInstaller was a good solution for this task. It got converted very easily under Windows, however I cannot make it working with Linux (was probing it on two different Ubuntu machines). The original Python program could be reduced to the simple two-line code:

```
from numpy import log
print '%8.6f' % log(5)
```

Which is working fine when called like:

```
anton@op:~/bin$ python test_numpy.py
1.609438
```

After compilation in PyInstaller, it gives me that error:

```
anton@op:~/bin/dist/test_numpy$ ./test_numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/anton/bin/build/test_numpy/out00-PYZ.pyz/numpy", line 153, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/anton/bin/build/test_numpy/out00-PYZ.pyz/numpy.add_newdocs", line 13, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/anton/bin/build/test_numpy/out00-PYZ.pyz/numpy.lib", line 8, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/anton/bin/build/test_numpy/out00-PYZ.pyz/numpy.lib.type_check", line 11, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/anton/bin/build/test_numpy/out00-PYZ.pyz/numpy.core", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name multiarray
```

So the problem is related to numpy library been not imported correctly.

I have tried adding hidden hooks as pyinstaller suggested, but nothing helps and I am always getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: One-file executable isn't linux way. Make a deb package with dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am not making a one-file version. I know that it is not the perfect way, but I need to make a multi-platform simple-to-install stand-alone version. Any ideas why the PyInstaller is not accepting numpy? I even tried to reinstall python and numpy, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this problem.

This is what I have found on hithub:

> The executable that PyInstaller builds is not fully static, in that it still depends on the system libc. Under Linux, the ABI of GLIBC is backward compatible, but not forward compatible. So if you link against a newer GLIBC, you can't run the resulting executable on an older system. The supplied binary bootloader should work with older GLIBC. However, the libpython.so and other dynamic libraries still depends on the newer GLIBC. The solution is to compile the Python interpreter with its modules (and also probably bootloader) on the oldest system you have around, so that it gets linked with the oldest version of GLIBC.

So it appeared that the current stable PyInstaller version could be outdated. As it was not practical to downgrade all the packages, I upgraded the PyInstaller to the latest development release (3.0.dev2) and voilà! Everything is working now with all the dependencies correctly processed without any custom hooks.

Hope that could help someone.